# How to access different endpoints between two express servers running on different containers

Tags: node.js, docker, express, routes, microservices

How do I make a request to another server running on a different container from another container? They are all on the same network and I use docker-compose to operate them.

I can access the authentication endpoints easily because it is defined within this server as shown below.

```
// Use login routes
app.use('/api/auth', routes.auth);
```

How do I access endpoints defined in a different server(different container)? I have tried using [http-proxy](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/tree/v0.21.0#readme) as follows but my code breaks.

```
app.use('/api/tasks', proxy({ target: 'http://localhost:5004/api/tasks'}));
```

In short, I want to access tasks server routes through the usermanagement server.

kindly advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like there is an [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy) package for just that.

```
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var app = require('express')();

app.use('/proxy', proxy('www.google.com'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you are using `docker` for containers. You can simply create a docker network then attach the containers to it. This will allow you to call the container with its name for example `http://fooAuth:1339` but you need a api call.

Also you can use `Envoy/Istio` a service mesh (but this is hard to implement and configure if you are a begginer) to determine the paths and direct your requests to the responsible app.

Comment: you mean like app.use('/api/tasks', proxy({ target: 'http://fooAuth:1339/api/tasks'}));

Comment: I meant that also you need to require the package like `var {createProxyMiddleware} = require('http-proxy-middleware');` or `var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware').createProxyMiddleware;`

Answer (score 0):

Start the two containers using a `docker-compose` file. There are instructions and links to tutorials [here](https://forum.zeebe.io/t/how-to-put-my-client-into-a-container/844/6?u=jwulf)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running both containers with the same docker-compose configuration file where each container is defined as a service, you will be able to use the service name as the container's hostname from your JavaScript code.

Given the following `docker-compose.yml`, for example:

```
services:
  usermanagement_server:
    build: ./usermanagement_server
  tasks_server:
    build: ./tasks_server
```

The above configuration will allow you to do the following:

```js
app.use('/api/tasks', proxy({ target: 'http://tasks_server/api/tasks'}));
```

From the [docker-compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links#links):

> ...by default, any service can reach any other service at that service’s name.

Comment: Both containers are running on the same docker-compose file.. and linked with the same bridge network. The challenge is adding the routes, is ( app.use('/api/tasks', proxy({ target: 'http://tasks_server/api/tasks'})); ) correct?